# How do I find the argument that has a NA or NaN indicated in an error message?

Tags: r

My R script randomly stopped working and the error that it outputs is this:

```
Error in 1:(grep("null", x)[1] - 1) : NA/NaN argument
```

I pinpointed it down to this function:

```
plot_grid(plot_grid(pq1_plop, pq2_plop, pq3_plop, 
                    ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(5, 9, 13), align = "v"), 
          plot_grid(pq1_agged_diff_plot, pq2_agged_diff_plot, pq3_agged_diff_plot, NULL
                    , ncol = 1
                    , rel_heights = c(5, 9, 13, 1)
                    , axis = "l"
                    , align = "vh"
          ), 
          nrow = 1
          , rel_widths = c(10, 6)
          #, align = "v"
          #, axis = "t"
)
```

I've tried running `plot(pq1_plop)` and all the 5 other plop variables, and they all get plotted perfectly fine. I'm not sure how to triage this error and figure out where the Na/NaN argument is located, so I'd like any guidance with that.

If it helps, here are all the packages I use. I suppressed `ggpubr` since it was outputting some odd messages.

```
library(cowplot, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)
library(stringr)
```

ggpubr message without the suppression:

```
Loading required package: magrittr

Attaching package: ‘ggpubr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:cowplot’:

    get_legend
```

So I'm not sure if that's related, as my Googling hasn't helped much

Comment: So you are running function inside function?: `plot_grid(plot_grid...`

Comment: Yeah I am. I think I originally did that because I'm trying to plot 2 plots together. I'm not very experienced with plotting this many plots all at once, so I'll take any suggestion. I unfortunately have to plot all at once since the plot gets rendered all at once in PowerBI